# Need a very specific RegEx Filter

Tags: regex

Alrighty, so.
I need a single regex that catches all cases of "[variable]" except for "[Swear]".
I got the first part figured out,`^\[[a-zA-Z]+\]` works well enough for me.
I also somewhat got the second part - `^((?!\[Swear\]).)*$`gets everything except for the specific phrase "[Swear]"

Now, I sadly dont know how to combine the two - I want it to catch anything that has square brackets around it, except for when the content of the brackets is "Swear"

If you need more details I can try to be more specific

Comment: Though I believe @Ryszard's solution best, you could instead match `\[Swear\]|(\[[a-zA-Z]+\])`, the only relevant matches being the ones captured to group 1. The idea is to match what you don't want and to capture what you do want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```php
\[(?!Swear\])[a-zA-Z]+\]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/A6OvMN/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Swear                    'Swear'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
```